# Quais seriam casos reais de uso de programação funcional no mundo .NET (F#)?

Tags: .net, f#, programação-funcional

Recentemente *(ok, já faz alguns bons meses)* estive me interando da [linguagem F#](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%E2%99%AF), que é a resposta da Microsoft em oferecer uma linguagem de programação funcional na plataforma .NET.

Porém ainda não ficou bem claro pra mim os reais casos e vantagens do uso deste paradigma sobre as "tradicionais" linguagens orientadas a objeto que já estão bem consolidadas (neste caso, C# ou VB.NET).

Portanto:

- Em quais casos a [programação funcional](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_funcional) viabiliza soluções que a [programação orientada a objeto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos) é falha / morosa / impossível?
- Há algum caso de uso desta linguagem / paradigma em projetos conhecidos (ou *open-source*)?
- Do ponto de vista profissional, para as demandas de nosso mercado (brasileiro), vale a pena aprofundar os conhecimentos neste paradigma?

Comment: Acho que é o mesmo que perguntar "quais os casos reais onde eu usaria a matemática?"

Comment: sua pergunta é muito ampla, e talvez fuja da proposta do site. Mas espero que essa resposta seja o que você queria saber.

Comment: Pra dar uma ideia do uso de programação funcional na indústria, tem essa página aqui http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_industry

Comment: @korbes: Bacana! Obrigado pelo link.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Embora o paradigma de programação **Imperativo** seja o mais popular entre programadores [profissionais], ele é apenas um entre vários meios de se "dar ordens" a um computador. Alem dele e do **Funcional**, temos também a **Programação em Lógica** (ex.: Prolog), ***Dataflow*** (ex.: o motor interno de uma planilha), ***Function-Level*** (os programas não manipulam dados, mas sim outros programas), etc. E, é claro, a mais conceitual/teórica **Máquina de Turing** - à qual todos os paradigmas anteriores são computacionalmente equivalentes.

Cada um desses paradigmas apresentam vantagens e desvantagens, e é comum à medida que as linguagens de programação "evoluem" que elas incorporem aspectos dos demais paradigmas. A principal razão pela qual se usa um paradigma ou outro é sua **expressividade**: a princípio, todos poderíamos estar programando em Máquinas de Turing, mas além da dificuldade de se ler/escrever/compreender tais programas eles também seriam por demais extensos em relação ao que fazem de útil. Da mesma forma, paradigmas diferentes oferecem um grau de expressividade maior para domínios específicos (ainda que a linguagem como um todo seja Turing-completa).

Quanto à **F#** em particular, vou citar [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/928124/520779) a uma pergunta similar no Stack Overflow em inglês:

> Minha expectativa é que F# será usada para pedeços/peças de alguns sistemas especializados - as partes que envolvem *threading* complexo / matemática / cálculos financeiros / modelagem / etc, onde F# se adequa bem. Na maior parte das outras áreas (IU, Camada de Acesso a Dados, etc), uma linguagem de propósito geral como C# parece (na minha opinião) preferível.
>
> Uma das vantagens de F# é que (em teoria) você pode provar que o código está funcionando, em vez de somente testá-lo. O suporte a *threading* (graças à imutabilidade e o uso assíncrono de `!`) também é bom (embora PLINQ pode competir em *threading*).

(Comentário: discordo do autor dessa resposta no sentido que é sim possível provar que um programa imperativo está correto - só é mais trabalhoso...)

Não posso comentar sobre o nosso mercado, uma vez que não participo do "ecossistema" Microsoft (preferindo desenvolver em software livre), mas de um modo geral a abertura das mentes dos programadores brasileiros para a programação funcional creio que seria muito bem vinda!

Comment: Legal! Muito obrigado pela sua explicação. Uma aula pra mim.

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que entendi da linguagem, o uso dela seria algo semelhante ao do **matlab**.

E seria utilizada onde você necessita realizar cálculos matemáticos complexos.

No próprio link que você passou sobre [programação funcional](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_funcional) há o seguinte trecho:

> Linguagens de programação funcionais, especialmente as puramente
>   funcionais, tem sido mais usadas academicamente que no desenvolvimento
>   comercial de software

Na área comercial é mais comum você encontrar uso na área de processamento de imagens(ou vídeo).

Isso não significa que uma aplicação inteira seria feita nessa linguagem, mas uma parte do processamento seria calculado por um *script* escrito nela.

Um exemplo pratico de uso: o sistema da folha de pagamento do estado onde trabalho tem toda sua parte visual(os módulos e telas que os funcionários operam) feitas em uma linguagem que facilite a criação de *forms*. Mas o processamento do calculo da folha de pagamento, que resulta em um volume gigantesco de cálculos, é rodado em scripts **C/C++**. A prioridade nesse caso, foi ganhar em processamento, já que os cálculos em si não envolvem funções tão complexas.
Tudo compõe um único sistema, mas com algumas partes escritas em linguagens diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado @Guilherme pela sua resposta. Sua abordagem já me esclareceu que o uso é direcionado, e não uma tendência generalizada. Era o que eu precisava confirmar.

Comment: As duas primeiras linhas da sua resposta estão erradas. Matlab é uma linguagem especializada para computação numérica, F# é uma linguagem de propósito geral tal como Ruby, Haskell, Clojure, C# etc.